# Как выбрать значения которые есть в одной таблице, но нет в другой?

Tags: sqlite, android, sql

Есть две таблицы, нужно выбрать значения которые есть в одной таблице, но нет в другой

```
 SELECT groups._id, groups.group_name   FROM groups INNER JOIN test  
 ON  groups. _id !=  test._id
```

и так

```
  SELECT groups._id, groups.group_name   FROM groups , test  
  WHERE  groups._id !=  test._id
```

но выводит все записи таблицы groups

Answer (score 2):

Разобрался

```
   SELECT groups._id, groups.group_name   FROM groups  LEFT JOIN test  
   ON  groups._id =  test._id 
   WHERE test._id  IS NULL
```